# stat_ellipse() returns "Error in if (all(abs(w - w0) < tol)) break :"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've this df:

```
df <- data.frame(
                    measure = c(196.7,194.0,212.4,174.8,214.8,217.5,232.6,246.3,257.4,255.3,269.7,261.7,299.4,156.4,15.0,123.8,194.8,154.1,199.5,247.6,276.7,221.9,114.5,256.6,293.3,230.6,287.0,109.2,41.5,151.5,218.2,213.1,241.2,239.4,185.4,5.8),
                    score = c (0,0,7,0,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,11,8,5,7,0,0,0,0),
                    time = c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30),
                    factors = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C","B","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
                    cluster = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,1,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,1,3)
)
```

I'm trying to plot both scatter plot and clusters using `stat_ellipse()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=score, y=measure))+
stat_ellipse(aes(fill=factor(cluster))) +
geom_point(aes(colour=factors, shape=factors))
```

I received:

```
Error in if (all(abs(w - w0) < tol)) break :
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `df[df$cluster == 2, ]`, it has constant `score`:

```
   measure score time factors cluster
7    232.6     0   10       B       2
8    246.3     0   10       B       2
9    257.4     0   10       C       2
10   255.3     0   10       C       2
11   269.7     0   10       C       2
12   261.7     0   10       C       2
13   299.4     0   30       B       2
20   247.6     0   30       C       2
21   276.7     0   30       C       2
24   256.6     0   30       C       2
25   293.3     0   30       C       2
26   230.6     0   30       C       2
27   287.0     0   30       C       2
33   241.2     0   30       B       2
34   239.4     0   30       B       2
```

So there's no way to draw an ellipse. For instance, others are fine:

```
ggplot(df[df$cluster != 2, ], aes(x=score, y=measure))+
    stat_ellipse(aes(fill=factor(cluster))) +
    geom_point(aes(colour=factors, shape=factors))
```